# Где изучить правила пунктуации для вопросов и ответов?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, ответы, правила

В мой ответ были внесены правки пунктуации: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1363175/revisions

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где изучить правила пунктуации при написании вопросов и ответов? Прочие правила тоже приветствуются, чтобы учитывать их на будущее.

Comment: Бесполезные правки.

Comment: @Qwertiy с чего это вдруг бесполезные? Ответ хоть на 0,5%, но улучшили же ) Вы видно имеете ввиду, что-то иное, связанное с правкой?

Comment: Для постов, достаточно общих правил русского языка, изученных, например, в школе.

Comment: @Kromster ну такое. Не понятно, зачем точка после "Демо", двоеточие после "Объяснение" как бы нужно, но в целом не играет роли. В сумме по субъективным ощущениями читаемость ухудшена на 0,5%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как уже упомянули в комментариях, каких-то специфических правил русского языка, на которые нужно обратить внимание при написании вопросов и ответов, нет. Т.е. достаточно руководствоваться общими правилами грамотного составления текстов. Если что-то нужно прояснить по самому языку, то можно обратиться к соответствующему сайту в составе сети Stack Exchange: https://rus.stackexchange.com/

В конкретной упомянутой правке я особого смысла не вижу. Может редактор планировал какую-то шляпу на этом заработать. Вы как автор можете любые правки откатывать, главное, чтобы не было вандализма и "войны правок".

В случае же, если правки делаются участниками с недостаточным уровнем репутации, они попадают на проверку в очередь. Там есть ограничение по минимальному кол-ву изменений, т.е. такая правка бы вовсе не попала в очередь. Но если вдруг предлагается действительно что-то такое несущественное часто такие правки просто отклоняют как "не приносящие ничего полезного" и только отвлекающие других (проверяющих) участников.

Comment: `Может редактор планировал какую-то шляпу на этом заработать.` — банальное набивание очков в очереди проверок. после правки ответ попал в очередь первых ответов [и тем же редактором был «проверен»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/685561).